# Return enum from remote service with .aidl interface

Tags: android, service, aidl

I am using .aidl interface to create a remote service in Android. And i want/need use enum values.

This is my object class:

```
package com.example.remoteservice;



import java.util.Date;

enum State {Located, Missing,Failure}; 

public class PositionObject {


    State Status;


    public PositionObject(
            State status) {
        super();

        this.Status = status;

    }

    public PositionObject() {
    }


    public int getStatus() {
        return Status.ordinal();
    }

    public void setStatus(State status) {
        this.Status = status;
    }




}
```

this the class where are the function of remote service:

```
    private final IRemoteService.Stub mBinder = new Stub() {



        @Override
        public int getstatus() throws RemoteException {
            return capture.remote.getStatus();
        }


}
```

and this the .aidl interface and .aidl.java:

```
package com.example.remoteservice;

// service interface
interface IRemoteService {
    //sample method
    int getstatus();


}

@Override public int getstatus() throws android.os.RemoteException
{
android.os.Parcel _data = android.os.Parcel.obtain();
android.os.Parcel _reply = android.os.Parcel.obtain();
int _result;
try {
_data.writeInterfaceToken(DESCRIPTOR);
mRemote.transact(Stub.TRANSACTION_getstatus, _data, _reply, 0);
_reply.readException();   THIS IS THE LINE WICH PRODUCES ERROR
_result = _reply.readInt();
}
finally {
_reply.recycle();
_data.recycle();
}
return _result;
}
```

and when in my second project i call to this funcion, for example with log.i crash:

```
Log.i("telo","telo"+String.valueOf(mRemoteService.getstatus()));
```

logacat:

```
02-25 19:44:03.818: E/AndroidRuntime(21900): FATAL EXCEPTION: serviceThread
02-25 19:44:03.818: E/AndroidRuntime(21900): Process: com.example.grafica, PID: 21900
02-25 19:44:03.818: E/AndroidRuntime(21900): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-25 19:44:03.818: E/AndroidRuntime(21900):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1471)
02-25 19:44:03.818: E/AndroidRuntime(21900):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
02-25 19:44:03.818: E/AndroidRuntime(21900):    at com.example.remoteservice.IRemoteService$Stub$Proxy.getstatus(IRemoteService.java:274)
02-25 19:44:03.818: E/AndroidRuntime(21900):    at com.example.grafica.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:300)
02-25 19:44:03.818: E/AndroidRuntime(21900):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

What happens? i think it is OK. no?

thanks

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: what is capture.remote? what is capture? try to Log.d them gefore calling getStatus()

Comment: Captue is an object of the class when I set and get values of class Positionobject, anda remote is an object of Positionobject class.

Comment: Produces also a error, not show nothing if i put Log.d between Log.i and return capture.remote.getStatus();

Comment: call Log.d(TAG, "capture " + capture)

Comment: 02-26 09:42:59.028: D/telo(4232): capture com.example.remoteservice.Sistole_main@42db4f50

Comment: and do the same replacing capture to capture.remote

Comment: 02-26 09:48:50.838: D/telo(4567): capture com.example.remoteservice.PositionObject@42db79f0

Comment: hmm, also is  Status not null?

Comment: ahhh, i think than now i understand you... this is with status 02-26 09:56:12.968: D/telo(4943): capture null
so the problem is the way how i set status no?

Comment: yes you probably pass null in new PositionObjec()

Comment: ok i will check this!! thanks so much for you support!!! i'll tell you result

Comment: The probles was this. I was using a constructor without params, but the extrange this is that when this enum was int not gives problem, but now yes.  THANKS SO MUCH!!